# Is there a service for taking an enitre Access application and having it fully operate in the cloud?

Tags: ms-access, migration

I would like to take a large Microsoft Access application and migrate all of its forms, tables, queries into the cloud and be able to access it fully online without having to rely on my computer to process anything.

Is this it all possible? Any suggestions?

Perhaps Microsoft Azure?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Comment: Aside from Gustav's answer, the general answer to all other aspects in the question is "No".  Access does not satisfy current best practices and design patterns. That is true not only of a web/cloud app, but Access forms and data-access models do not even conform to good modern desktop design standards.  A proper web application should be re-designed based on current technology.  (I would not be surprised if there was some 3rd party tool that would attempt such a thing, but I would be very suspicious especially of all aspects of security surrounding such an implementation.)

Comment: This question is likely off topic.  From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Install Access on a *terminal server* and access the application via *Remote Desktop* or as a *Remote App*.